# Storing NSString in an array and then displaying it in another view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have UserDetails class:

```
@interface UserDetails: NSObject{

  NSString* resourceName;
  NSNumber* resourceId;

  }
```

I have an object("user")  of this class in class B which I am passing in another Class C. Now I need to store the resourceNames of different users in an array and display it in another class C(TableviewController). I am using the following statements in class C:

```
NSMutableArray *arr (declaration)

Implementation:

 arr=[[NSMutableArray array] retain];
 arr=user1.resourceName;  (user1 is an object of UserDetails data class).
```

Error : Incompatible pointer types assigning to "NSMutableArray" from "NSString".

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directly assigning stringValue "resourceName" to "arr",which will give u error.If u wanna store the resourceName in array ..try this

```
arr=[[NSMutableArray array] retain]; // your initialization
 [arr addObject:user1.resourceName];
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
arr=user1.resourceName;
```

with

```
[arr addObject:user1.resourceName];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit mixed up but your main problem is assigning a string to an array (which the compiler tells you about), what you should be doing is adding the string to the array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array]; 
[array addObject:user1.resourceName];
```